# How to top-align and word-wrap a form panel field in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, word-wrap, formpanel

How can I make the multiline form field `Description`**word-wrap** and **top-align** its text?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    clearExtjsComponent(regionContent);
    var panel_form = new Ext.FormPanel({
        labelWidth: 100,
        frame:true,
        style: 'margin: 10px',
        title: 'Test Product ID#2',
        bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width: 500,
        defaultType: 'textfield',

        items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'ID',
                value: '2',
                name: 'id',
                disabled: true,
                width: 370,
                style: 'text-align: right',
                name: 'id',
                disabled: true,
                width: 50,
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Product',
                value: 'Envelope',
                name: 'product',
                width: 370,
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Description',
                value: 'Having a good idea about the functional requirements and client-side technology choices, the next step was to decide how things were going to be on the server side. To channel all communications with my web client I decided to use an http handler. For the articles repository, a binary file would go very well with my simplicity and short-construction-time requirements. Any data access and business logic would be placed inside class libraries.',
                name: 'description',
                width: 370,
                height: 100,
            },{
                    ...
```

When I try `xtype: 'textArea'`, I get the error `types[config.xtype || defaultType] is not a constructor`:

```
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Description',
            value: 'Having a good idea about the functional requirements and client-side technology choices, the next step was to decide how things were going to be on the server side. To channel all communications with my web client I decided to use an http handler. For the articles repository, a binary file would go very well with my simplicity and short-construction-time requirements. Any data access and business logic would be placed inside class libraries.',
            height: 100,
            xtype: 'textArea',
            name: 'description',
            width: 370,
        },{
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed the `defaultType` to `'textfield'`, which is the `xtype` you want to use on all fields except for the Description field. For that field you'd want an `xtype` of `'textarea'`. This will top align the text and word wrap automatically as a typical html textarea would. Keep in mind that with a lot of text you'll likely see a scrollbar in the textarea. If you want to avoid scrollbars take a look at the `TextArea` config options `grow`, `growMax`, and `growMin`.

**Example:**

```
   {
       xtype: 'textarea',
       fieldLabel: 'Description',
       value: 'Having a good idea about the functional requirements and client-side technology choices, the next step was to decide how things were going to be on the server side. To channel all communications with my web client I decided to use an http handler. For the articles repository, a binary file would go very well with my simplicity and short-construction-time requirements. Any data access and business logic would be placed inside class libraries.',
       name: 'description',
       width: 370,
       height: 100,
    }
```

Comment: When I try that I get the error `types[config.xtype || defaultType] is not a constructor`. I posted my code above, is there something I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Ah my bad Edward, it should be all lowercase 'textarea'. Typically the available xtypes follow this pattern. Sorry for the confusion, my answer has been updated :D